# Complete graph $K_n$ with $n$ edges in a Hamiltonian cycle removed

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $K_n$ be the complete (undirected) graph on $n$ vertices. We know that there are $\frac{(n-1)!}{2}$ Hamiltonian cycles in $K_n$. Now fix a Hamiltonian cycle and remove all the edges in it from $K_n$. How many Hamiltonian cycles are left?

I've been trying my hand at this problem for a while but I'm stuck on how to proceed. There seems to be a brute force principle of inclusion-exclusion approach by first counting how many
Hamiltonian cycles pass through a given subset of edges in the removed cycle, but there are just too many cases to consider.

Is there a sleeker method to approach this problem? Perhaps something involving generating functions, if the answer doesn't have a nice simplified closed form?

Comment: https://oeis.org/A002816  Always good to enumerate the first few cases.

Comment: @EdPegg Thanks! So I guess an exact formula is hopeless...? I'm also still interested in the possibility of a generating function

Comment: The oeis page links to a report in which an exact formula is given. The quantity is called $q_n$ in the report.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I will post the exact formula, given in page 6 of [this report](http://i.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/80/829/CS-TR-80-829.pdf) as $q_n$, as informed by Gerry in the comments.

$$ q_n = \frac{(n-1)!}{2}+ \left( \sum_{1 \leq k < n} (-1)^k \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k} {k-1 \choose j-1} {n-k \choose j} \frac{n-k}{j} \frac{(n-k-1)!}{2} 2^j \right) +(-1)^n$$

I wonder if there is a way to simplify this.